# Why are my qt file dialogs rendered incorrectly?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently creating a GUI with Qt 5.6 and I want to let the user open a file. I do this using the following code in my main window class:

```
#include <QFileDialog>
...
void MainWindow::loadScene()
{

    QString loadPath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                        tr("Choose a scene file"), QString("."),
                        tr("Scene files (*.keyScene)"));

    if(!loadPath.isEmpty())
        resourceManager->loadScene(loadPath.toStdString());
}
```

I get the following dialog:

[Screenshot of open file dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7orKl.png)

The system I use is Ubuntu 16.04, I've also tested on Ubuntu 14.04 and Mint 17.3. I get the exact same result on all of them.

When I compile the project in Windows everything works fine.

**EDIT**

It was suggested I play around with the DontUseNativeDialog flag when creating a file dialog, I can get a working Qt style file dialog with the following code:

```
QFileDialog dialog(this);
dialog.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog::AcceptOpen);
dialog.setOption(QFileDialog::Option::DontUseNativeDialog, true);
if(!dialog.exec())
    return;
```

So the question is actually why native file dialogs aren't rendered correctly.

Comment: Are those OS-es on the same machine?

Comment: Have you tried to to create a exec a ̀QFileDialog` manually and play with `DontUseNativeDialog` flag?

Comment: @JeffreyvandeGlind These tests were both on Ubuntu and Windows on two different machines.

Comment: @jpo38 I've manually made a QFileDialog and I've set the DontUseNativeDialog flag to true. This gives me a working Qt style dialog. That means only native dialogs don't render correctly, I'll update the question.

Comment: @Frank Ok, I was thinking it might be due to a driver or hardware defect. I am not sure if the dialog is rendered using hardware acceleration by default, and uses software acceleration when using DontUseNativeDialog.

Comment: I'm having same issue in Windows. But in my case native dialogs not working only in Qt creator, it is working without an issue after build the App. Still searching for a solution since I want to save some test files generated by the App.